# Sort on multiple values with List js

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, google-chrome, sorting

Trying to get [list.js](http://www.listjs.com/) plugin to sort on multiple values. I.e. it should sort on category first and then sort on title within the category, alphabetically.

Here's a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/8E7cH/

Works in Safari and Firefox. But in Chrome it doesn't.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="category">
        <span class="sort">Category</span>
    </li>
</ul>


<main id="articlelist">
    <ul class="list"><li>
            <span class="category">Design</span> 
            <span class="overflow">
                <a class="title" href="http://someurl.com/adventure-gear/">Adventure gear</a>
            </span>
        </li><li>
            <span class="category">Architecture</span> 
            <span class="overflow">
                <a class="title" href="http://someurl.com/djennes-mud-mosque/">Djenné’s Mud Mosque</a>
            </span>
        </li><li>
            <span class="category">Cities</span> 
            <span class="overflow">
                <a class="title" href="http://someurl.com/edge-city-sao-paulo/">Edge City (São Paulo)</a>
            </span>
        </li><li>
            <span class="category">Cities</span> 
            <span class="overflow">
                <a class="title" href="http://someurl.com/istanbul/">Istanbul</a>
            </span>
        </li><li>
            <span class="category">Cities</span> 
            <span class="overflow">
                <a class="title" href="http://someurl.com/jenin/">Jenin</a>
            </span>
        </li><li>
            <span class="category">Architecture</span> 
            <span class="overflow">
                <a class="title" href="http://someurl.com/previ/">PREVI</a>
            </span> 
        </li><li>
            <span class="category">Cities</span> 
            <span class="overflow">
                <a class="title" href="http://someurl.com/rebuilding-beirut/">Rebuilding Beirut</a>
            </span>
        </li><li>
            <span class="category">Architecture</span> 
            <span class="overflow">
                <a class="title" href="http://someurl.com/revolutionary-housing-argentina/">Revolutionary housing in Argentina</a>
            </span>
        </li><li>
            <span class="category">Cities</span> 
            <span class="overflow">
                <a class="title" href="http://someurl.com/shenzhen/">Shenzhen</a>
            </span>
        </li><li>
            <span class="category">Architecture</span> 
            <span class="overflow">
                <a class="title" href="http://someurl.com/high-line/">The High Line</a>
            </span>
        </li><li>
            <span class="category">Cities</span> 
            <span class="overflow">
                <a class="title" href="http://someurl.com/unreal-estate-london/">Unreal Estate (London)</a>
            </span>
        </li>
     </ul>
</main>
```

JS

```
var articleList = new List('articlelist', {valueNames:  [ 'category', 'title' ]});

$('span.sort').click(function() {
        articleList.sort('title', { asc: true })
        articleList.sort('category', { asc: true }) 
});
```

Comment: I have just tryed it on Chrome browser and it works correctly!

Comment: Really? What platform? I'm on OSX with version 31.0.1650.63. Pressing Category gives me this (not alphabetically ordered titles) http://i.imgur.com/NyNmZlj.png

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
var articleList = new List('articlelist', {valueNames:  [ 'category', 'overflow' ]});

$('span.sort').click(function() {
        articleList.sort('overflow', { asc: true })
        articleList.sort('category', { asc: true }) 
});
```

I think that you must use the class attribute value of the tag `span`.

Comment: A bit better, but you can press the button repeatedly and it'll keep on "sorting" http://jsfiddle.net/C3VfG/

Comment: I've just edit my answer, and the repeated sorting is solved, but I think that it sort the list based on the value of all what's inside `<span>` tag, i.e. `<a ....> </a>`

Comment: @INT I think that the plugin Listjs cannot sort a list on multiple value !

Comment: I think so too. Actually went with Tiny Sort instead. http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

Comment: You need to pass your own sorting function, and only then, you can specify how the sort action behaves: https://github.com/javve/list.js/issues/193